# How to stop playing sound in Xode with AudioToolbox framework?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, audiotoolbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop a sound using the same button that plays it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765595/stop-a-sound-using-the-same-button-that-plays-it)

Hi, I create a button in my app that play a sound

If I click on this button while the sound is playing it starts again but don't stop the previous one, how can I stop any sound before playing the next one?

Thanks

Edit:

This is the code I use for playing the sound

```
-(IBAction)avviaSuono:(id)sender{
    CFBundleRef mainBundle= CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle,(CFStringRef) @"fileName", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

that play the file fileName.mp3

Comment: Another person asked this question after you and has solved it; you can refer to that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765595/stop-a-sound-using-the-same-button-that-plays-it