# Stop a sound using the same button that plays it

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

Pretty simple, I'm using one button that generates a random number and then with a switch/case, it animates an image and plays a sound. My problem is that when you press the button again, the sound that was playing before doesn't stop and the sound overlaps.

Here's the code:

```
- (IBAction) pushme: (id) sender{
int random = (arc4random()%10);
switch (random) {
    case 0:  {
            [ANIMATION NUMBER 0]

            NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],@"/sound0.wav"];
            SystemSoundID soundID;
            NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
        }
        break;
    case 1:  {
            [ANIMATION NUMBER 1]

            NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],@"/sound1.wav"];
            SystemSoundID soundID;
            NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    } break; //Lots more cases after this one
```

I know that this is not the best way to do it, declaring the same variable over and over.
but is there a way to stop it before it plays another one?

Comment: LOL i just discovered the answer to my own question.

Comment: That's great! Please post the answer here so others can benefit from your research.

Comment: @Nicolas: sorry, I meant add it as an "Answer", below. This way the question does not appear in searches as unanswered. Thanks!

Comment: @JoshCaswell i cant because as a new user i cant answer it before 8 hours have passed.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, can u add it please?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I always forget these rules. I will add it as a Community Wiki post.

Comment: Nice. My current solution is rather crude. I just have a button counter and do a modulus 2 on it. Odd for stop, even for start :). Works fine though!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just dicovered the answer to my own question.

What I did was

1. Declare `SoundSystemID soundID;` in the header.
2. Add this line before the random number gets generated: `AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);`

Remember that if you are going to play the sound again, you will need to load the resource again after disposing of it.

Thank you guys, anyway.